# Should I keep a bathroom door open or closed to keep it from expanding?

Tags: bathroom, wood, doors, exhaust-fan, bathroom-fixtures

Should I keep the bathroom door open or shut after a shower to keep it from expanding?  What if the fan is on as well?

Comment: How humid is the rest of the interior, especially right outside the bathroom door?

Comment: Whether it is open or closed has no bearing on it expanding due to excessive moisture. Though if the room isn't properly vented with an exhaust fan, leaving it open may reduce the overall moisture in that one area.

Comment: When the door was painted. were all six (6) surfaces painted in the same way?  Warping is more problematic than simple expansion...

Comment: Does the door swing in or out?  Is the door so tight, that if it expands it sticks? Why are you trying to prevent the expansion?

Answer (score 2):

Leave the door open to reduce humidity, better yet: knock out the hinge pins, pull the door  and lay the door flat on some sawhorses and give it a good glossy paint job paying special attention to the top and bottom edges.